Material UI text components right-to-left direcrion in material version 6 and pigment css
how i can change direction of material UI component using pigment CSS?
i set global direction in root of <body> and set direction in pigment config but material UI text components are left-to-right direction.
how i can fix this issue?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you check the MUI documentation? They have a detailed step-by-step guide to setting up RTL (which is what you want, I suppose?): https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/right-to-left/
Adding the dir="rtl" property to html elements might help with certain components not working.
If you're migrating from v5, check out the Migration guide's tips on RTL: https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migrating-to-pigment-css/#right-to-left-support
If you want further help, please provide more info and maybe some sample code.
